# Change of variable problems in probability

Tags: probability, self-learning

If $X$ is a continuous random variable with positive values,find it's Cumulative distribution function (CDF) and it's probability density function (PDF) for $$Y = \sqrt{X}$$

This was a detable question on another topic so I made it a seperate one.

Can someone explain how do we solve this problem to it's end? (putting some theory/ explanations in between would be appreciated. My goal is to understand the concepts that are behind this and be prepared for problems of equal difficulty). Thank you.

---

> ***Added by A.F.*** This was originally the "third pattern" of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/488049/8348).  Possible solutions may exist on the linked question.

Answer (score 1):

$$P(\sqrt{X}\leq t)=P(X\leq t^2)=F(t^2)$$
where $F$ is the cumulative distribution function of $X$. Therefore pdf of $Y$ is 
$$\frac{dF(t^2)}{dt}=f(t^2)\times2t$$
where $f$ is the pdf of $X$.

See any elementary book on probability and statistics, for a better understanding of transformation of random variables.

Comment: I think you need to fix the dot in the second formula

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that the CDF for $X$ is denoted by $F_X(x)$ and similarly for $Y$. The you have:

$$
F_Y(t)=\Pr(Y\leq t)=\Pr(X\leq t^2)= F_X(t^2)
$$

> $$
> f_Y(t)=2t\times\frac{d F_X}{dt}(t^2)=2t\times f_X(t^2)
> $$

Answer (score -1):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}{{\rm e}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert #1 \right\vert}$
$$
{\rm P}_{Y}\left(Y\right)\,{\rm d}Y
=
{\rm P}_{X}\left(X\right)\,{\rm d}X
\quad\imp\quad
\color{#ff0000}{{\rm P}_{Y}\left(Y\right)}
=
{\rm P}_{X}\left(X\right)\,{{\rm d}X \over {\rm d}Y}
=
{\rm P}_{X}\left(X\right)\,2Y
=
\color{#ff0000}{2{\rm P}_{X}\left(Y^{2}\right)Y}
$$

Comment: Faulty notations.